# multiply keys of dictionary to each other

Tags: python, list, dictionary

the dictionary I have is:

```
teachers = [
    {'Name':'Mahdi Valikhani', 'phoneN':'+989012345679', 'hours':6, 'payment':50000, 'salaries':[2]*[3]},
    {'Name':'Ali Afaghi', 'phoneN':'+989011234567', 'hours':8, 'payment':45000},
    {'Name':'Hossein Alizadeh', 'phoneN':'+989011234867', 'hours':8, 'payment':45000},
]
```

and I want to somehow multiply hours to payment to have the **salary**!
I have tried multiplying but it gives me an error and the error says you can not multiply strings into integers!

help please!

Comment: also tried to multiply in the dictionary that I got this error (can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each `dict` and compute salaries and add new `key` and `value` like below:

```
teachers = [
    {'Name':'Mahdi Valikhani', 'phoneN':'+989012345679', 'hours':6, 'payment':50000},
    {'Name':'Ali Afaghi', 'phoneN':'+989011234567', 'hours':8, 'payment':45000},
    {'Name':'Hossein Alizadeh', 'phoneN':'+989011234867', 'hours':8, 'payment':45000},
]

for dct in teachers:
    dct['salaries'] = dct['hours']*dct['payment']
    
print(teachers)
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Mahdi Valikhani', 'phoneN': '+989012345679', 'hours': 6, 'payment': 50000, 'salaries': 300000}, 
{'Name': 'Ali Afaghi', 'phoneN': '+989011234567', 'hours': 8, 'payment': 45000, 'salaries': 360000}, 
{'Name': 'Hossein Alizadeh', 'phoneN': '+989011234867', 'hours': 8, 'payment': 45000, 'salaries': 360000}]
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all remove `'salaries':[2]*[3]` from the first dict, and then run

If you want to update the existing dictionaries.

```py
for t in teachers:
   t["salary"] = t["hours"] * t["payment"]
```

Note: make sure `hours` and `payment` should be numeric, if you are not sure, then you can convert it

```py
for t in teachers:
    try:
        t["salary"] = int(t["hours"]) * float(t["payment"])
    except ValueError:
        pass  # fallback case
```